# Using IPython object? in ipdb

Tags: python, ipython, pdb, ipdb

IPython provides handy object inspection tool, by writing `object?` to REPL.

Can this be accessed in [ipdb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipdb)? It doesn't seem to be available as built-in command.

Currently I see the help gives out just the standard pdb help:

```
ipdb> help

Documented commands (type help <topic>):
========================================
EOF    bt         cont      enable  jump  pdef    psource  run      unt
a      c          continue  exit    l     pdoc    q        s        until
alias  cl         d         h       list  pfile   quit     step     up
args   clear      debug     help    n     pinfo   r        tbreak   w
b      commands   disable   ignore  next  pinfo2  restart  u        whatis
break  condition  down      j       p     pp      return   unalias  where
```

Comment: The code for the object inspector is at [`IPython.core.oinspect`](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/core/oinspect.py). A quick grep in the `ipdb` source for `oinspect` doesn't yield any results though, so it looks like it's not exposed in `ipdb`.

Answer (score 2):

Object inspection in the IPython shell prints the docstring and other information.  The **ipdb** debugger can print the docstring, which is part of what IPython object inspection is doing. Just type

```
ipdb> print(object.__doc__)
```

For example, to inspect the built-in **sum** function

```
ipdb> print(sum.__doc__)
sum(iterable[, start]) -> value

Return the sum of an iterable of numbers (NOT strings) plus the value
of parameter 'start' (which defaults to 0).  When the iterable is
empty, return start.
ipdb>
```

This is most of the way to what happens in the IPython shell

```
In [5]: sum?
Docstring:
sum(iterable[, start]) -> value

Return the sum of an iterable of numbers (NOT strings) plus the value
of parameter 'start' (which defaults to 0).  When the iterable is
empty, return start.
Type:      builtin_function_or_method

In [6]:
```

Another alternative is to just embed an IPython shell as a debug breakpoint.  This is nice but I've not found a way to cleanly exit when such a debug breakpoint is embedded in a loop.

```
from IPython import embed
embed()  # debug breakpoint
```

An even better approach that I just learned about is to use **!** in ipdb, then things work the same as in the IPython shell.

```
ipdb> !help(sum)
Help on built-in function sum in module builtins:

sum(iterable, start=0, /)
  Return the sum of a 'start' value (default: 0) plus an iterable of numbers

  When the iterable is empty, return the start value.
  This function is intended specifically for use with numeric values and may
  reject non-numeric types.

ipdb>
```